# Stringifying a Java Object throwing Error in JSON.parse Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have defined a class Email having following details:
`Email`:

```
String name;
String subject;
List<String> attachment;
String jsonContent;   
....
```

In above class, `jsonContent` variable is loaded with a strinigified json object.
Once an Email object is created, I am stringifying the whole Email object and sending to client.

I need to parse Email object in client and render it in UI.
But it throws parsing error for Email object in client, i.e.

`JSON.parse(emailString);`

because `jsonContent` field is having double quotes within it.
It is a problem of stringifying a JAVA object having a `jsonContent` variable which is already stringified.

One way to fix it is define `jsonContent` variable as a object rather than as a String.
Is there any other fix for it?

Example Email JSON:

```
    {
    "id": "e4682ec0-a7c3-4f4d-abcd-f404f5fdb1eb",
    "entityType": "email",
    "subject": "Presentation 1",
    "from": "aaa <a@a.com>",
    "to": [
        "undisclosed-recipients:;"
    ],
    "cc": [],
    "bcc": [
        "jack.porter@forwardaccelerator.com"
    ],
    "recievedDate": 1423101398000,
    "recievedDateString": "Wed, 4 Feb 2015 12:26:38 -0800",
    "bodyText": " Please find the link to my recent presentation",
"jsonContent": "{
  "typeOfMail": "NormalMail",
  "normalMail": {
    "mailType": "NormalMail",
    "paragraphs": [
      "Pleasefindthelinktomyrecentpresentation"
    ]
  }
}"
}
```

Comment: What is the error and what is the content of `jsonContent` in Java and in the browser? If you provide more detail, it will allow someone to help.

Comment: @SeanMickey I have added a sample Email JSON

Comment: @SeanMickey I am sorry for that, I have updated JSON, it will still give invalid JSON, but If you remove jsonContent part, it will give valid JSON

Comment: have you tried escaping double quotes with an escaped slash? `\\\"`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Yes, I have tried that.. It did not work for me

Comment: oh wait.. you are trying to put json into json string. now I get it o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape a lot of strings to get stuff as strings.

to store a json object in a json object you need to escape it.
so

```
  "jsonContent": "{
  "typeOfMail": "NormalMail",
  "normalMail": {
    "mailType": "NormalMail",
    "paragraphs": [
      "Pleasefindthelinktomyrecentpresentation"
    ]
  }
}"
```

becomes

`"jsonContent": "{\"typeOfMail\": \"NormalMail\",\"normalMail\":{\"mailType\":\"NormalMail\",\"paragraphs\":[\"Pleasefindthelinktomyrecentpresentation\"]}}"`

Now if you want to compile it in java, this is how it should look like if you would type it manually as an Java string(execute snippet)

```js
var json =  {
    "id": "e4682ec0-a7c3-4f4d-abcd-f404f5fdb1eb",
    "entityType": "email",
    "subject": "Presentation 1",
    "from": "aaa <a@a.com>",
    "to": [
        "undisclosed-recipients:;"
    ],
    "cc": [],
    "bcc": [
        "jack.porter@forwardaccelerator.com"
    ],
    "recievedDate": 1423101398000,
    "recievedDateString": "Wed, 4 Feb 2015 12:26:38 -0800",
    "bodyText": " Please find the link to my recent presentation",
"jsonContent": "{\"typeOfMail\": \"NormalMail\",\"normalMail\":{\"mailType\":\"NormalMail\",\"paragraphs\":[\"Pleasefindthelinktomyrecentpresentation\"]}}"
}
console.log("This is the json object having a string with json");
console.log(json);
console.log("This is it parsed as string");
var x = {hello:JSON.stringify(json)};
console.log(JSON.stringify(x).substring(10,JSON.stringify(x).length-2));
document.getElementById('content').textContent = JSON.stringify(x).substring(10,JSON.stringify(x).length-2);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

And this is how it would look like in a JSON file/request answer thats sent

```
{
    "id": "e4682ec0-a7c3-4f4d-abcd-f404f5fdb1eb",
    "entityType": "email",
    "subject": "Presentation 1",
    "from": "aaa <a@a.com>",
    "to": [
        "undisclosed-recipients:;"
    ],
    "cc": [],
    "bcc": [
        "jack.porter@forwardaccelerator.com"
    ],
    "recievedDate": 1423101398000,
    "recievedDateString": "Wed, 4 Feb 2015 12:26:38 -0800",
    "bodyText": " Please find the link to my recent presentation",
"jsonContent": "{\"typeOfMail\": \"NormalMail\",\"normalMail\":{\"mailType\":\"NormalMail\",\"paragraphs\":[\"Pleasefindthelinktomyrecentpresentation\"]}}"
}
```

Now I don't see why you want jsonContent as a string, as you could just pass it as an object(remove the quotes surrounding it so you get

```
"jsonContent": {
  "typeOfMail": "NormalMail",
  "normalMail": {
    "mailType": "NormalMail",
    "paragraphs": [
      "Pleasefindthelinktomyrecentpresentation"
    ]
  }
}
```

and if you need it as string in javascript you can just do `JSON.stringify(json.jsonContent);` to get the same result easier.